# How to change mesh color

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, color

How do I change my mesh color so I can identify them separately. The default color of every object in my 3d-window is Grey. I'm not talking about the Material Property itself. I'm talking about something sort of this nature.
[image]

A very similar question was asked on here in 2017. I don't how to attach a link to it, so here is a screenshot of an Answer to the said question. Hopefully someone will explain better because I'm confused.

Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're talking about the *Random* mode in the *Viewport Shading* panel:

[image]

Comment: Yes. Definitely is. Thank you very much.